# R: how to add a column into a data matrix with first 1599 rows as "redwine" and next 5000 rows as "whitewine"

Tags: r

I want to add a column named "Type" into a data matrix which has 6497 rows.

for 1 to 1599 rows in the column, I want to put in value"redwine", and for 1600 to 6497 rows, I want to put in value "whitewine".

How can I realize this code in R?

Thank you so much because I am a new learner.

Comment: I suggest you use some tutorials for beginners as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a data.frame called x, you could use

```
x$Type <- NA
x$Type[1 : 1599] <- "redwine"
x$Type[1600 : 6497 ] <- "whitewine"
```

if x is a matrix:

```
cbind(x, c(rep("redwine",1599), rep("whitewine",6497 - 1599)))
```

Comment: You could also do `x$Type <- 'whitewine'; x$Type[1:1599] <- 'redwine'`

Comment: As this answer worked, I assume that `x` is a data frame and not a data matrix. They are different things in R.

Comment: `rep` is vectorised too - so `rep(c("redwine","whitewine"), c(1599, 6497 - 1599))` also works. Or even `rep(c("redwine","whitewine"), diff(c(0,1599,6497)))` if you want to get fancy

Answer (score 0):

## Hello data.frame

The data frame is a convenient storage device for problems in R. It is a lot like the matrix that you spoke of in your problem statement. Here is one way to use a `data.frame` object in R to contain your 1 column of data with N rows.

### Create your lists, containing the data you want

```
list1 <- rep("red",1599)# replicate is build into R, it will clone the first argument, by the second argument's number of times, and return it as a list.
list2 <- rep("white", 4898)
list3 <- list(list1, list2) # this is a list object, containing 2 other lists, accessible via this notation list3[[1]] gets your red wines, and list3[[2]] gets your white wines.
list_flattened <- unlist(list3) # This turns a list of lists, into 1 list of unified items.

df <- data.frame(Type=list_flattened) # this creates a matrix like object, with a column named Type and its entries (or rows) as that big list we generated.

> head(df)# helper function to print the first 5 rows of the df
  Type
1  red
2  red
3  red
4  red
5  red
6  red
> tail(df) # helper function to print the last 5 rows of the df
      Type
6492 white
6493 white
6494 white
6495 white
6496 white
6497 white
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No need for a `list` and then `unlist` - just `c(list1,list2)` would do it.